Hardware Keyboard MAUI / Blazor MAUI Hybrid
We have a search box that modifies parts of the UI. When we are running on iOS or Android we hide some parts in order to make space for the virtual keyboard whenever the input field is focused. However, on few occasions the user has instead connected a hardware keyboard to the tablet/iPad. In those cases there is a hardware keyboard it doesn't make sense to hide the UI components. Is there any way in MAUI to detect if there is a hardware keyboard being used?

There is no api for maui can detect if the physical keyboard is connected. But you can call the platform native code to do that.
            bool isphysicakeyboardconnected;
#if ANDROID
            isphysicakeyboardconnected = Platform.CurrentActivity.Resources.Configuration.Keyboard != Android.Content.Res.KeyboardType.Nokeys;
#elif IOS
            isphysicakeyboardconnected = GameController.GCKeyboard.CoalescedKeyboard !=null;
#endif

